Ensuring two task in a QThread don't overlap
I'm writing an application using PyQt6 to monitor and control an external serial device, and thus I need to send both read and write instructions, taking around 100ms to get a response.
I've created a QThread and a respective worker for the functions that communicate with the device, like so:
class SerialWorker(QObject):
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device
    updateUI = pyqtSignal()

    def read(self):
        self.device.read()
        self.updateUI.emit()

    def write(self):
        self.device.write()

My SerialWorker is signaled when to read and to write appropriately from another thread, but I find that often this causes it to try to read while writing and vice versa. I had thought that putting both tasks in the same thread would prevent this, but apparently I was wrong.
Is there a way to make sure the two tasks are not attempted at the same time?
I've tried having the read and write tasks on separate threads, then tried putting them in the same one. Also tried to stop one task from starting when the other was running with simple while loops, but without success.

Assuming you're communicating with the same device, using separate threads is certainly inappropriate. You should only use one thread and eventually use proper instruments such as locks or semaphores. Note that Qt has QSerialPort, have you considered it?

I noticed there was a QSerialPort, but was avoiding it because I am communicating with the device using a pyserial-based library that has the commands already mapped out.
How would one use locks and semaphores in this case?
